# Advertised P2P messaging addresses changes when compatibilityZoneURL is informed

Tags: corda, cordite

I'm trying to setup an environment on separate machines:

- Server1: Node
- Server2: Bridge
- Server3: Float

When I execute the node registration or:

```
java -jar corda.jar --just-generate-node-info
```

The address on nodeInfo-XXX is generated correctly, pointing to Server3 IP (float), which I've put on p2paddress on node.conf.

But when I inform the compatibilityZoneURL parameter to a configured Cordite Network Map service, and start the node, the nodeInfo-XXX and the "Advertised P2P messaging addresses" just changes to the Server1 IP, although this IP doesn't appear in node.conf.

My node.conf:

```
myLegalName="O=Node Test,L=Sao Paulo,C=BR"
p2pAddress="float-server-IP-or-alias:10005"
rpcSettings {
    useSsl = false
    standAloneBroker = false
    address="0.0.0.0:10031"
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10061"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
useTestClock = false
enterpriseConfiguration = {
    externalBridge = false
    mutualExclusionConfiguration = {
        on = true
        updateInterval = 20000
        waitInterval = 40000
    }
}
devMode=false
compatibilityZoneURL : "http://10.102.32.106:8080/"
keyStorePassword = "cordacadevpass"
trustStorePassword = "trustpass"
```

> Edit: I'm using Corda Enterprise v3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to try adding the following line to your node.conf:

```
detectPublicIp = false
```

From the docs:

> This flag toggles the auto IP detection behaviour, it is enabled by default. On startup the node will attempt to discover its externally visible IP address first by looking for any public addresses on its network interfaces, and then by sending an IP discovery request to the network map service. Set to false to disable.

Let us know if this works.